# Basic descriptive statistics on an irregular data set

Tags: anova, dataset, standardization, diversity

I have not used my stats in a while and was interested in how the group would handle the following:

I have a multi-year insect data set that has irregularities in trapping effort, trap type and area of trap size within a specific trap type. I am interested in obtaining measures of relative abundance, dominant species, species diversity and richness numbers.

I was considering using a basic ANOVA and Shannon-Weiner Diversity index and looking at the data based on hours and area of trapping effort.

Any thoughts...

Comment: I'm doing basic descriptive analysis on a data set which is pretty complex too. I'm just plotting the dependent measures against the factors now though, trying to see if there are any interesting patterns... Would be great if there are more ways to describe the data!

Answer (score 1):

It **sounds** like you will need some form of multilevel model (aka hierarchical linear models, mixed models and a few other terms).  This would be needed to deal with the dependencies in your data set. That is, the amount you trap at site A in 2009 is going to be related to the amount you trap at site A in 2008. It may be that you also have some spatial dependencies.

But first, I'd do a lot of plotting of the data. One plot would be a scatterplot with time on the X axis, whatever you are interested in (e.g. diversity index) on the y-axis, and points colored for different site and perhaps sized for amount of effort.